# arcpy "The table name is invalid"

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, lidar, error-000210

I wrote a script that, ideally, loads raw .las (LiDAR data) files into a geodatabase, then creates a terrain from the multipoint files that are created.  When I run the script though I get:

> ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output C:\Users\peter\Desktop\test.gdb\bare_earth\1las
>   The table name is invalid.
>   Failed to execute (LASToMultipoint)

So far the only thing I can figure out is that Windows 7 keeps changing my folder permissions to read-only, but I can still manually create, edit, and delete in the directories.

```
import os
import arcpy, math, glob
from arcpy import env

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
#make workspace in memory
arcpy.env.workspace = "in_memory"

#define parameters using GetParameter in ArcMap
geodatabase = arcpy.GetParameter(0)         #0)input Geodatabase
outfeaturedataset = arcpy.GetParameter(1)   #1)Desired Name for the feature class
projection = arcpy.GetParameter(2)          #2)coordinate system
terrain_name = arcpy.GetParameter(3)        #3)Name of the Terrain
class_code = arcpy.GetParameter(4)          #4) the return class code to use
lasdirectory = arcpy.GetParameter(5)        #5) directory to get las data in

#designate directory where .las files are located
os.chdir (lasdirectory)

created_FC_tool = arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(geodatabase, outfeaturedataset, projection)
created_FC = created_FC_tool.getOutput(0)
#Create a Terrain


arcpy.CreateTerrain_3d (created_FC, terrain_name, 1.24605815948, 50000, '', 'WINDOWSIZE', 'ZMIN', 'NONE', 1)

output_terrain = os.path.join (created_FC, terrain_name)
arcpy.AddTerrainPyramidLevel_3d (output_terrain, 'WINDOWSIZE', '2.5 1000; 5 2000; 10 4000; 20 8000; 40 16000')
#process the .las file and add to the feature dataset and terrain



for LASfiles in glob.glob("*.las"):
    print LASfiles
    pointinfo = "point_file_information"
    #Get Pointfile information
    arcpy.PointFileInformation_3d(LASfiles, pointinfo, "LAS", "", projection)

    #get average point spacing variable
    pointspacing = arcpy.SearchCursor (pointinfo)
    field = "Pt_Spacing"
    for row in pointspacing:
        avg_space = (row.getValue(field))
    print avg_space

    #convert las  to multipoint

    #create lable for multipoint file
    listlable = list(LASfiles)
    del listlable[-4]
    multipointlable = ''.join(listlable)
    print multipointlable

    print created_FC
    outputPlable = os.path.join (created_FC, multipointlable)
    arcpy.LASToMultipoint_3d(LASfiles, outputPlable, 1.5, class_code, "", "INTENSITY", projection, "las", 1)



    print outputPlable

    outputPlable_parameters = outputPlable + ' Shape masspoints 1 0 40 true false R06305328las_embed <None> false'
    print outputPlable_parameters
    arcpy.AddFeatureClassToTerrain_3d (output_terrain, outputPlable_parameters)

#Build the terrain
arcpy.BuildTerrain_3d (output_terrain)
```

If it is a Windows 7 problem I don't know what I'm going to do as my work computer is locked down by our help desk.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inside a Geodatabase, there are certain ways you can't name a table or Feature Class.  Beginning with a number is one of those ways.

Validating Table and Field Names in Python:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z00000020000000

Try renaming your table to las_1 or something and see if it works

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's always some mundame detail that I miss.  Thanks again, I probably would have never stumbled on that.